# QuickBooks SDK PHP Fatal error: Error Num.: 1146

Tags: php, quickbooks

I have got this log in the PHP Error log. Previously the code was running. Now it can not authenticate itself. I do not know why it has been occuring.

The Code for Authentication is-

```
 function _quickbooks_custom_auth($username, $password, &$qb_company_file){
    global $user, $pass;
    if ($username == $user and $password == $pass){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The Error Log-

```
 [05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Error Num.: 1146
Error Msg.:La table 'qb_2015_11_29.quickbooks_log' n'existe pas
SQL: 
            INSERT INTO 
                quickbooks_log 
            (
                batch,
                msg, 
                log_datetime
            ) VALUES (
                0, 
                'Handler is starting up...: array (\n  \'qb_company_file\' => NULL,\n  \'qbwc_min_version\' => NULL,\n  \'qbwc_wait_before_next_update\' => NULL,\n  \'qbwc_min_run_every_n_seconds\' => NULL,\n  \'qbwc_version_warning_message\' => NULL,\n  \'qbwc_version_error_message\' => NULL,\n  \'qbwc_interactive_url\' => NULL,\n  \'autoadd_missing_requestid\' => true,\n  \'check_valid_requestid\' => true,\n  \'server_version\' => \'PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /quickbooks/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_auth.php\',\n  \'authenticate\' => \'_quickbooks_custom_auth\',\n  \'authenticate_dsn\' => NULL,\n  \'map_application_identifiers\' => true,\n  \'allow_remote_addr\' => \n  array (\n  ),\n  \'deny_remote_addr\' => \n  array (\n  ),\n  \'convert_unix_newlines\' => true,\n  \'deny_concurrent_logins\' => false,\n  in C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql\Mysqli.php on line 374

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP Stack trace:

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\docs\web_connector\example_web_connector_auth.php:0

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP   2. QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server->__construct() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\docs\web_connector\example_web_connector_auth.php:47

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP   3. QuickBooks_Adapter_Server_Builtin->setClass() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\QuickBooks\WebConnector\Server.php:202

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP   4. QuickBooks_SOAP_Server->setClass() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\QuickBooks\Adapter\Server\Builtin.php:68

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP   5. QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers->__construct() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\QuickBooks\SOAP\Server.php:210

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP   6. QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers->_log() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\QuickBooks\WebConnector\Handlers.php:281

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP   7. QuickBooks_Driver->log() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\QuickBooks\WebConnector\Handlers.php:385

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP   8. QuickBooks_Driver_Sql->_log() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\QuickBooks\Driver.php:1460

[05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP   9. QuickBooks_Driver_SQL_Mysqli->_query() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql.php:2329

 [05-Dec-2015 08:03:47 America/New_York] PHP  10. trigger_error() C:\wamp\www\quickbooks\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql\Mysqli.php:374
```

Comment: Hard for us to help here, since we cannot see what you can see, we have no access to your system. Obviously some part of your code has an issue with inserting data into your database. So either how the error claims that table or database really does not exist, or, if the code is somewhat sloppy, maybe you have no access to your database management system.

Comment: Database Access is OK. May be issue is in code.

Comment: Then why don't you post that code? Or do you expect us to guess it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error Msg.:La table 'qb_2015_11_29.quickbooks_log' n'existe pas

This means that the table does not exist, or is not created properly in the framework.

If it was previously working, it could be a transient connection issue.